# How to calculate the sum of a vector without using loop or std::accumulate()?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I'm trying to implement an Euclidean vector for my programming assignment. I need to overload operator* to provide dot product calculation for two vectors with arbitrary same dimension. 
As 3D vector for example:

Vector<3> v1, v2; //two 3D vectors.

double dotProduct  = v1 * v2;

The value of dotProduct should be v1[0]*v2[0]+v1[1]*v2[1]+v1[2]*v2[2]

So, my problem is how to get this value without using any explicit loop and std::accumulate() operation in numeric.h header file? Because those are forbidden in this assignment.

P.S. I may use functor(self defined) together with STL algorithm.

Comment: 1) Do you know that the operands will always be three-dimensional? 2) What is a `Vector`?

Comment: As you've written `dotProduct = v1[0]*v2[0]+v1[1]*v2[1]+v1[2]*v2[2]`, it appears to me that you have an idea of how to approach this. What have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: There is no `<numeric.h>`, only `<numeric>`. [Your answer is on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric). (Hint: the dot product is a type of what?)

Comment: What you're trying to compute is normally called an inner product. Searching existing algorithms with that mind might be fruitful.

Comment: std::for_each may serve well when using builtin loops isn't permitted.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - us physicists take offense at the phrase "normally called an inner product". It's always been a dot product, and always will be! <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker: Granted, "normally" was the wrong word -- but I was trying to hint at what to look for in the standard library without basically just writing the code for him...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid explicit loops and algorithms in general (not just `std::accumulate`), you could use `std::valarray`s instead:

```
std::valarray<double> a;
std::valarray<double> b;

// code to put data in a and b goes here

double dotProduct = (a * b).sum();
```

I've used `double` as the type here, but you can (of course) use whatever type makes sense for the data/situation you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::inner_product`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product

```
double dotProduct = std::inner_product(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use explicit loops, perhaps your teacher is asking you to use recursion.

```
template<int N>
int VectorSum(const Vector<N>& v1, const Vector<N>& v2, int m) {
  if(m) return v1[m]*v2[m] + VectorSum(v1, v2, m-1);
  return v1[0]*v2[0];
}

template<int N>
int operator+(const Vector<N>& v1, const Vector<N>& v2) {
  return VectorSum(v1, v2, N-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to read a text about it， so I copy it for you. may be it's introduced in the book :C++ Templates: The Complete Guide.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int DIM,typename T>
struct DotProduct {
    static T execute(const T v1[],const T v2[]);
};
template<int DIM,typename T>
T DotProduct<DIM,T>::execute(const T v1[],const T v2[]) {
    return v1[0]*v2[0] + DotProduct<DIM-1,T>::execute(v1+1,v2+1);
};

template<typename T>
struct DotProduct<1,T> {
    static T execute(const T v1[],const T v2[]);
};

template<typename T>
T DotProduct<1,T>::execute(const T v1[],const T v2[]) {
    return v1[0]*v2[0];
};

int main()
{
    int v1[] = {1,2,3}; 
    int v2[] = {4,5,6};
    int r2 = DotProduct<3,int>::execute(v1,v2);
    std::cout << r2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A nice example for using template and recursion! Thanks a lot!